# What is InternalFlutterGpuTestClass_Method?

Tags: flutter

I'm seeing it in stack traces of a production iOS app, but can't find anything about it:

Thread 0 not responding

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x00000001e01b10f4  semaphore_wait_trap
1   libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001a0a49f48
2   UIKitCore   0x000000019b9f21c8
3   UIKitCore   0x000000019b9f22d8
4   Flutter 0x0000000103c62360
5   Flutter 0x0000000103c61528
6   Flutter 0x0000000104221968  **InternalFlutterGpuTestClass_Method**
7   Flutter 0x0000000103c83bfc
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001a0a476a4